# Event Handlers Item Added event is not working in sharepoint library 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, development, event-receivers, troubleshooting

How can I troubleshoot the issue of Item Added event is not firing up.

I checked sharepoint logs, but couldn't find any clue there.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Are you tried to debug your solution by attaching to w3wp services? Also please it will be useful for us if you add more details to can help you faster

Comment: I observe this issue only in production sites but not in dev sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the below one of the alternatives

Note: please make sure that user have necessary sufficient permissions  to do  the below actions.

1)**Event log**
Try to create a event log in the event receiver and log the values there

```
using (EventLog eventLog = new EventLog("Application")) 
{
    eventLog.Source = "Application"; 
    eventLog.WriteEntry("Log message example", EventLogEntryType.Information, 101, 1); 
}
```

2) **Degbugging**
we can debug the event receiver by attaching the  W3wp.exe process.     [Debug SharePoint Applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650703.aspx)

3) **custom log writer** creating a custom log writer  and  write the lof to the local drive folders in the sharepoint server
**Note:** Since you are writing the event receiver for document library please check the both Item added and updated event receiver. The **item added** was fired while  uploading the document and Item Updated will fire while updating the metadata columns